# How can I prevent tabs menu on visual code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, menubar

My menu bar on visual code is hidden, I would like to know how can I get it back please.
[image]

Comment: You say "menu bar" but you highlighted the tabs.  Do you want to see more tabs or the menu bar (File Edit etc.) above the tabs?

Comment: Yes i mean tabs

Comment: @DanCr Then why did you use the name of the menu bar in the question and description?

Comment: See these settings: `Workbench > Editor: Show Tabs` and `Workbench > Editor > Limit: Value`

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Ubuntu 20.04 You can use `ALT` key.

[image]

---

On Win 10

1. `Ctrl + Shit + P`
2. Preferences: `Open Keyboard Shortcuts.`
3. Type: *menu bar*, you should see : **View Toggle Menu Bar**.

[image]

4. Click, `Change Keybinding` and set your **own** shortcut for example `Alt+A`
5. Close settings, and it's done, Now it should **works like a charm** ;-)